# Hyperledger Fabric java how to use getQueryResult()

Tags: java, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to use the getQueryResult() method in a transaction but i'm not able to understand what type of string i have to pass in the method. 
I have an asset composed by and id, name, surname and an hash. I want to verify that the hash doesn't alreaty exists in the ledger. 
The underlying database is couchdb.
All the string i used returned me an error. Could someone help me to use the right syntax? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string you have to pass must be in couchdb selector syntax, see here:
https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/find.html#find-selectors
The hyperledger fabric tutorial mentions this here:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/couchdb_tutorial.html#build-the-query-in-chaincode
So for example if your asset has the field "hash" you could query like so:

```
String queryHash;
QueryResultsIterator<KeyValue> results = stub.getQueryResult("{\"selector\":{\"hash\":\"" + queryHash + "\"}}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Save your data in JSON format, and then later passon 'couch db' query to this method to get answer.